# Need Concrete Example of Where a Frequentist Clustering Technique Outperforms the Existing Bayesian Clustering Techniques

Tags: bayesian, clustering, predictive-models, frequentist

I'm looking for a concrete example of frequentist clustering outperforming Bayesian clustering (using the best Bayesian algorithm for the problem, using the testing criteria below).

There are many types of clustering techniques, such as K-means and DBSCAN.  There are many different ways of measuring how well clustering works, and I'm using *one* here.

To make this problem specific, I'm looking for the following criteria:

1. The results need to be realistic and generalized, not some rare case.
2. The clustering needs to result in a model/specification that will be used to cluster unseen data (to make a prediction), that will run on the new (additional) data without user intervention.
3. The underlying ideal number of clusters is between 4 and 9. (To limit the scope to the problems I'm interested in - not binary, and not many clusters.)
4. It doesn't matter what is being clustered (text, images, numbers, etc.)
5. The Bayesian and frequentist clustering models will be compared with categorical cross entropy:
   [image]